# Android: adding the camera icon to action bar on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to an a camera icon to my action bar on android studio, but I can not see any icon. I can see is the "camera" text in my overflow. Below is my `me.xml` file which is in my menu folder, and also is below is my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
      android:title="@string/menu_logout_lable"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_edit_friends"
      android:title="@string/menu_edit_friends_label" />

    <item
      android:id="@+id/action_camera"
      android:title="@string/menu_camera_label"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out why, in my xml file, on the item for the camera

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_camera"
android:title="@string/menu_camera_label"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
android:showAsAction="always"

/>
```

, i changed

```
 android:showAsAction="always"
```

to

```
 app:showAsAction="always"
```

the difference been changing android: to app: .

Thanks